# Parent element searching not working as imagined

Tags: jquery, parent, alerts

Can anyone tell me why the alert in [this Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisbrown/6qQhc/78/) is not writing out on the page?  Does it have to do with the using of `parent()`?

I'm not understanding why i can't get the alert to aleast pop up...even if there is no value.

FYI, I'm looking to return `<fieldset class="vertsection1">`.

[jsFiddle code example](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisbrown/6qQhc/78/)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The fiddle you linked is asking for the class of an element that does not have a class. the parent of the 'continue' link is a div that ha an `ID` of `continue` and a `name` of `continue` but does _not_ have a class. Expanding on that more; you want `$(this).parent().parent().attr('class');` to get that class.

Comment: Please try converting className() to className in the javascript method

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var clSection = $(this).parents('fieldset').attr('class');
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7JxbZ/)

Comment: This is another great approach.  This one makes alot of sense too.  I will plug this in and see if it performs any faster...Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the response grc.  I'm actually show/hiding 4 fieldsets on my page and this was just on section.  I have a "next section" link at the bottom of each fieldset to initiate the closing of the current fieldset and the opening of another.  I wanted to use the same link to control validation of each fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out,

http://jsfiddle.net/6qQhc/80/

You need to use .attr('class')

Also, you have already given an id to the link, so you can do $('#assign').click() instead of $('#continue a').

Lastly, try using console.log(yourMessage) rather than alert(yourMessage) - more friendly!

Comment: I actually have 4 fieldsets in a form that shows and hides based on a "next section" link at the bottom of each field set.  I wanted to be able to look for each link depending on which on was being shown in each section.  I will give this coding a try in the morning and report back. I appreciate the advice!

Comment: Thanks Rahul,  can you see console.log using Chrome?  I use firefox too, but I prefer Chrome these days?

Answer (score 0):

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/6qQhc/81/

Most jquery method returns list, not item.
BTW, className is a property, not method.